# Attach custom input source to a run loop in Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, input, nsrunloop

Does anyone know a way to attach custom input source to a run loop with Swift language ?
I am following this documentation : [Run Loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1) in particular: "Configuring Run Loop Sources", but I have not figured out how to use it with swift.